# Obtaining Sensor Data and motor control values?

Tags: webots

I am currently using Webots and new to the software framework. I need to implement a robot at the moment and get the **sensor data and motor control values** from it. The robot is a self-made robot and is not one of them already implemented tutorials. Can someone elaborate on how to get those values? I am trying to implement it in C++ if someone could help me with the syntax of the code to obtain the values?

Answer (score 2):

You should start by following the Webots tutorials, there is one specific for controller which explains exactly what you are trying to do and is available in c++: https://cyberbotics.com/doc/guide/tutorial-4-more-about-controllers?tab-language=c++

There is one tutorial for building your own robot too: https://cyberbotics.com/doc/guide/tutorial-6-4-wheels-robot?tab-language=c++

In any case, I would recommend following at least tutorials 1 to 6 to get familiar with Webots.